# Remove ListView items in android from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

May you help us with our school project it's due Thursday. we have a problem when we use push() to insert data to the Firebase Realtime Database we trying to remove values from randomly generated key and it works but only removed from the app but NOT in Realtime Database we can't figure out what is the problem, please we need your help

push() --> in Additem.class

private void StoreProductInformation() {

```
    Description = InputProductDescription.getText().toString();
    Pname = InputProductName.getText().toString();


    citem obj = new citem(Pname,Description );
    ProductsRef.push().setValue(obj);

    Toast.makeText(Additem.this, "Added To cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i =new Intent(this,shoppingcart.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

removeValue() --> in shoppingcart.class

```
list.setAdapter(myadapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(shoppingcart.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mylist.remove(positionToRemove);
                    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //myRef.child("key").removeValue();

                }});
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

[realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzlQI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution in which you can solve the problem would be to store that pushed ID as property under each object:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- shoppingcart
        |
        --- -N1kC...ZKwO 
        |     |
        |     --- name: "R"
        |     |
        |     --- qty: 3
        |     |
        |     --- key: "-N1kC...ZKwO" 
        |
        --- -N1kC...LO3- 
              |
              --- name: "Z"
              |
              --- qty: 10
              |
              --- key: "-N1kC...LO3-"
```

This also means that the class that holds those two fields (`name` and `qty`) should now also contain another field called `key`. So assuming that this class is called `Item`, to remove the clicked item from the adapter, as well from the database, please use the following lines of code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //Remove the item from the Realtime Database
    Item clickedItem = mylist.get(positionToRemove); 
    myRef.child(clickedItem.getKey()).removeValue(); 

    //Remove the item from the adapter.
    mylist.remove(positionToRemove);
    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}});
```

This will work if you have added public getters inside your class, otherwise, if you have access to the public field, then please use:

```
myRef.child(clickedItem.key).removeValue();
```

If you, however, consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) and a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of a ListView, then please check one of the following articles which you consider to be more appropriate for your use-case:

- [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf)

Or:

- [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)

Comment: we managed to store the pushed ID as property under each object but we get (Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: ')  error at 'Item clickedItem = mylist.get(positionToRemove);' . Item class contain constructor and getters & setters. We tried this solution 'Item clickedItem = new Item(); 
    myRef.child(clickedItem.getKey()).removeValue();' but still give error.

Comment: First of all, I have changed the order inside `onClick`. Please do it too. Besides that, if your `mylist` is defined to hold String objects, is wrong. It should be defined as `List<Item>`, right? Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: If we change  'ArrayList<String> mylist;' to  'List<Item> mylist;' we get error in the adapter witch is like 'ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter;  myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_test,R.id.dtext,mylist);' says that Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(x.shoppingcart, int, int, java.util.ArrayList<x.citem>)' , also we another error at adding '                   mylist.add("  "+ i.getName()+ "\n" + "  "+ i.getQty());'. says "add(x.citem)' in 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)

Comment: That's the normal behavior since you cannot add `Item` objects into a List of type String. So you change the List<String> into List<Item> everywhere in your code. And when you add objects to the list, add them like this `mylist.add(new Item("S", "4", "-N1kC...LO3-"))`. Does it work now as expected?

Comment: We did change it every where in our code.As for the adding we need the add to be from the user so we tried to make the adding like this ' mylist.add(new Item(i.name,i.qty,i.key));' then We tried to change the adapter from 'ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter; myadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_test,R.id.dtext,mylist);' to 'myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>; myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,R.layout.activity_test,R.id.dtext,mylist);'.And worked with no errors But we get another problem where the add appeared as email where it appears in the DB exactly like we wrote it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence. However, without seeing more code, I cannot be much of a help. That being said, I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: please check my new question as i added new info to make it clear as much as possible for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233155/remove-and-update-items-in-listview-at-firebase-database

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial problem?